# How to test promises with Mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, es6-promise, chai-as-promised

I'm using Mocha to test an asynchronous function that returns a promise.

What's the best way to test that the promise resolves to the correct value?

Comment: make a function which takes in `it` and returns a function that you call instead of it that does all this automatically. Your test function will need to start with `return getSomePromise()`

Comment: "When this assertion fails, it gets swallowed". To clarify, the exception that `value.should.equal` throws gets caught by the function calling the "success" callback. This is a feature of Promises/A+ to ensure that you can always handle any errors (exceptions or otherwise) in the "failure" callback at the end of the promise chain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mocha has built-in Promise support as of version 1.18.0 (March 2014). You can return a promise from a test case, and Mocha will wait for it:

```
it('does something asynchronous', function() { // note: no `done` argument
  return getSomePromise().then(function(value) {
    expect(value).to.equal('foo');
  });
});
```

Don't forget the `return` keyword on the second line. If you accidentally omit it, Mocha will assume your test is synchronous, and it won't wait for the `.then` function, so your test will always pass even when the assertion fails.

---

If this gets too repetitive, you may want to use the [chai-as-promised](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised) library, which gives you an `eventually` property to test promises more easily:

```
it('does something asynchronous', function() {
  return expect(getSomePromise()).to.eventually.equal('foo');
});

it('fails asynchronously', function() {
  return expect(getAnotherPromise()).to.be.rejectedWith(Error, /some message/);
});
```

Again, don't forget the `return` keyword!

Comment: Sorry i don't get it, i have a simple test `browser.url(..); title = browser.getTitle(); expect(title).to.equal('foo');` How would i use the `getPromise()`in my case?

Answer (score 4):

Then 'returns' a promise which can be used to handle the error.  Most libraries support a method called `done` which will make sure any un-handled errors are thrown.

```
it('does something asynchronous', function (done) {
  getSomePromise()
    .then(function (value) {
      value.should.equal('foo')
    })
    .done(() => done(), done);
});
```

You can also use something like [mocha-as-promised](https://github.com/domenic/mocha-as-promised) (there are similar libraries for other test frameworks).  If you're running server side:

```
npm install mocha-as-promised
```

Then at the start of your script:

```
require("mocha-as-promised")();
```

If you're running client side:

```
<script src="mocha-as-promised.js"></script>
```

Then inside your tests you can just return the promise:

```
it('does something asynchronous', function () {
  return getSomePromise()
    .then(function (value) {
      value.should.equal('foo')
    });
});
```

Or in coffee-script (as per your original example)

```
it 'does something asynchronous', () ->
  getSomePromise().then (value) =>
    value.should.equal 'foo'
```