# How to prevent false positives with mocha, promises, and catch blocks

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js

I want to take advantage of Mocha's built in promise support, but i'm having difficulty dealing with false positives when I want to test `catch` branches in my promise chains.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15058847/1048479) question gets closest to what I want, but the solution requires every developer on my project to add a `then` that will throw an error, and ensure that that error doesn't accidentally pass the test.

Because of this, i've had to revert to using the `done` style of tests, which relies on the built in timeout to catch errors instead of an assertion. This is less than ideal, but removes the chance of false positives.

```
var RSVP = require('RSVP');

function request (shouldSucceed) {
  if (shouldSucceed) {
    return RSVP.Promise.resolve('success');
  } else {
    return RSVP.Promise.reject(new Error('failure'));
  }
}

describe('request', function () {
  it('throws an error if shouldSucceed is not provided', function () {
    // this test is incorrectly calling `request`
    // which leads to it passing without actually testing
    // the behaviour it wants to
    return request(true)
      .catch(function (err) {
        expect(err).to.be.an.instanceof(Error)
      });
  });

  it('throws an error if shouldSucced is not provided (manual then block)', function () {
    // this test tacks a `then` onto the chain, to ensure `request`
    // actually throws an error as expected
    // unfortunately, it still passes since the assertion needs to do
    // a little extra work to ensure the type of error thrown is the
    // expected error
    return request(true)
      .then(function () {
        throw new Error('Not expected');
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        expect(err).to.be.an.instanceof(Error)
      });
  });

  it('throws an error if shouldSucceed is not provided (done syntax)', function (done) {
    // this assertion fails (as it should)
    // due to a timeout
    return request(true)
      .catch(function () {
         expect(err).to.be.an.instanceof(Error);
         done()
      });
  });
});
```

Output:

```
  request
    ✓ throws an error if shouldSucceed is not provided
    ✓ throws an error if shouldSucced is not provided (manual then block)
    1) throws an error if shouldSucceed is not provided (done syntax)


  2 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) request throws an error if shouldSucceed is not provided (done syntax):
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

Is there a cleaner way to tell mocha that I am expecting something to happen in a `catch` block, and that a successful resolution of the promise should be a test failure?

Comment: I don't get what you want. What is the syntax you'd like to use, and what "false positives" would you like to detect?

Comment: @Bergi I've updated the question to (hopefully) be clearer. Essentially I want to prevent the situation where a test is passing for the wrong reasons, e.g. i've created a promise chain that resolves in a way that bypasses my assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for

```
it('request(false) should throw an error', function () {
    return request(false).then(function() {
        throw new Error('unexpected success');
    }, function(err) {
        expect(err).to.be.an.instanceof(Error)
    });
});
```

See [When is .then(success, fail) considered an antipattern for promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) for an explanation of the difference to the code that you currently have.

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot of sense. It's unfortunate that there's always a requirement to manually handle cases, but I don't think there is a way around it :| I've accidentally forgotten to guard against a success and spent needless time debugging.

Comment: Well, you can always write a helper function like `expectToBeRejected` or so that wraps this, if you find yourself doing this often in tests.